# How to do Validation for update method (laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I try to use

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required'|unique:users',
            'adr' => 'required'
         ]);
```

But its not according to requirement 
Because every time if i want to update its says user is already taken because i not need to update email address
I want that if user not update email address it should create otherwise if user also update email address it should check first if it already found in DB it shows message email address already exist.

**function**

```
{
 $this->validate($request, [
        'place_holder' => 'required',
        'word_list' => 'required',
     ]);


    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    $input = $request->all();
    $user->fill($input)->save();
    session()->flash('msg',trans('Successfully Updated.'));
    return redirect()->route('user.index');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your validation for email on update should be as

```
'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$user->id,
```

Or you can write it as:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Validator::make($data, [
 'email' => [
    'required',
    Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id),
  ],
]);
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-unique)

Comment: it says $user->id, undefined @Amit Gupta

Comment: First you need to find the `user` like `$user = User::findOrFail($user_id)` and then use it in your validation rules. You must be getting `$user_id` from the update form.

Comment: working in same way...
Can you guide to use firstOrCreate/ firstOrNew method
if these method locate from db that it already found it should return already exist not should create a new one . if its same it should update @Amit Gupta

Comment: `firstOrCreate()` creates a entry in DB whereas `firstOrNew()` only creates new object but creates an entry in DB. You should use `firstOrCreate()` for this one.

Comment: its not working properly if its found email address its update otherwise it create new one. i dont want it create a new one and it should update on same id @Amit Gupta

Answer (score 0):

If you like to change login user mean, First you need find login user by auth,

```
$userId = Auth::user()->id;
```

Auth is

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

Then you can use like,

```
'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$userId.',id',
```

It is work when you are using this Auth.

Other wise you can pass by routes. like

in route,

```
Route::put('user_profile/{user_profile_id}', ...);

mywebsite.com/user_profile/1

$userId = $this->routes(user_profile_id);

'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$userId.',id',
```

I hope, it will help you.